# yarn upgrade не апгрейдит(

Tags: javascript, package, angular, inversion-of-control, yarn

Смотрю версии пакетов

```
C:\angular\w1>yarn outdated
yarn outdated v1.5.1
info Color legend :
 "<red>"    : Major Update backward-incompatible updates
 "<yellow>" : Minor Update backward-compatible features
 "<green>"  : Patch Update backward-compatible bug fixes
Package                           Current Wanted  Latest Package Type    URL

@angular/cli                      1.0.1   1.0.1   6.0.8  devDependencies https://github.com/angular/angular-cli
@angular/common                   4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  dependencies    https://github.com/angular/angular#readme
@angular/compiler                 4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  dependencies    https://github.com/angular/angular#readme
@angular/compiler-cli             4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  devDependencies https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/compiler-cli
@angular/core                     4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  dependencies    https://github.com/angular/angular#readme
@angular/forms                    4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  dependencies    https://github.com/angular/angular#readme
@angular/http                     4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  dependencies    https://github.com/angular/angular#readme
@angular/platform-browser         4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  dependencies    https://github.com/angular/angular#readme
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic 4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  dependencies    https://github.com/angular/angular#readme
@angular/router                   4.4.7   4.4.7   6.0.4  dependencies    https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/router
@types/jasmine                    2.5.38  2.5.38  2.8.8  devDependencies https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped.git
@types/node                       6.0.112 6.0.112 10.3.1 devDependencies https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped.git
bootstrap                         3.3.7   3.3.7   4.1.1  dependencies    https://getbootstrap.com/

codelyzer                         2.0.1   2.0.1   4.3.0  devDependencies https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer#readme
jasmine-core                      2.5.2   2.5.2   3.1.0  devDependencies http://jasmine.github.io

jasmine-spec-reporter             3.2.0   3.2.0   4.2.1  devDependencies https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter
karma                             1.4.1   1.4.1   2.0.2  devDependencies http://karma-runner.github.io/

karma-chrome-launcher             2.0.0   2.0.0   2.2.0  devDependencies https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher#readme
karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter  0.2.3   0.2.3   2.0.1  devDependencies https://github.com/mattlewis92/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter#readme
karma-jasmine-html-reporter       0.2.2   0.2.2   1.1.0  devDependencies https://github.com/dfederm/karma-jasmine-html-reporter#readme
protractor                        5.1.2   5.1.2   5.3.2  devDependencies https://github.com/angular/protractor
rxjs                              5.5.11  5.5.11  6.2.0  dependencies    https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS
ts-node                           2.0.0   2.0.0   6.1.0  devDependencies https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node
tslint                            4.5.1   4.5.1   5.10.0 devDependencies https://github.com/palantir/tslint.git
typescript                        2.2.2   2.2.2   2.9.1  devDependencies http://typescriptlang.org/
```

Обновляю ангулар командой

```
C:\angular\w1>yarn upgrade @angular
yarn upgrade v1.5.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Rebuilding all packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 0 new dependencies.
Done in 17.26s.
```

и ничего, помогите плиз, мб еще какой способ подскажите, как можно апгрейдить пакеты до последней версии

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать обновить пакеты из scope по очереди.

```
yarn upgrade @angular/cli @angular/core ...
```

Comment: Попробовал на cli и ничего, прошла установка, проверил и вот
`@angular/cli                      1.0.1   1.0.1   6.0.8  devDependencies`

Comment: Попробуйте `yarn upgrade @angular --latest`

Comment: В вашем package.json у версий должен стоять знак ^ для обновления. (^1.2.3 - разрешает обновление к версии новее 1.2.3)

Comment: Он там стоит и --latest я пробовал уже, все на той же версии стою